# How to use MySQL dump from a remote machine

Tags: mysql

How can I backup a mysql database which is running on a remote server, I need to store the back up file in the local pc.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try it with [Mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

```
#mysqldump --host=the.remotedatabase.com -u yourusername -p yourdatabasename > /User/backups/adump.sql
```

Comment: To use this command we should enable the access from remote on the mysql server?

Comment: @Gspoon Yes, it connects from the computer it runs on to the server, just like any other client.

Comment: If you get Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS error you should take a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/912162/mysqldump-throws-unknown-table-column-statistics-in-information-schema-1109 answer

Answer (score 57):

Have you got access to SSH?

You can use this command in shell to backup an entire database:

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p[password] [databasename] > [filename.sql]
```

This is actually one command followed by the `>` operator, which says, "take the output of the previous command and store it in this file."

Note: The lack of a space between -p and the mysql password is not a typo. However, if you leave the `-p` flag present, but the actual password blank then you will be prompted for your password. Sometimes this is recommended to keep passwords out of your bash history.

Comment: man mysql: If you use the short option form (-p), you **cannot** have a **space** between the option and the password.

Comment: Good one explaining the "no space" between -p and the actual password

Comment: if you use SSH you should mention SCP or SFTP usage to store the dump file in local PC as asked in the question

Comment: You should make sure that the firewall setting have the 3306 port open for TCP.

Answer (score 44):

No one mentions anything about the **--single-transaction** option. People should use it by default for InnoDB tables to ensure data consistency. In this case:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -h [remoteserver.com] -u [username] -p [password] [yourdatabase] > [dump_file.sql]
```

This makes sure the dump is run in a single transaction that's isolated from the others, preventing backup of a partial transaction.

For instance, consider you have a game server where people can purchase gears with their account credits. There are essentially 2 operations against the database:

1. Deduct the amount from their credits
2. Add the gear to their arsenal

Now if the dump happens in between these operations, the next time you restore the backup would result in the user losing the purchased item, because the second operation isn't dumped in the SQL dump file.

While it's just an *option*, there are basically not much of a reason why you don't use this option with mysqldump.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks man. I had mysql access to remote server, but couldn't dump DBs. The error was 
`mysqldump: Got error: 1044: "Access denied for user 'USER'@'%' to database 'DB_NAME'" when using LOCK TABLES` ,
but using `--single-transaction` option in `mysqldump` solved my problem.

Answer (score 20):

This topic shows up on the first page of my google result, so here's a little useful tip for new comers.

You could also dump the sql and gzip it in one line:

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p[password] [database_name] | gzip > [filename.sql.gz]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mysqldump -h [domain name/ip] -u [username] -p[password] [databasename] > [filename.sql]
```

Comment: Is it really `-p[password]` and not `-p [password]`?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes, and if you're password has special characters put it in quotes: `-p'pa$$w0rd!!!!'`

Answer (score 1):

Tried all the combinations here, but this worked for me:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8mb4 [DATABASE TO BE COPIED NAME] > [NEW DATABASE NAME]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't install `mysql_client` yet and using `Docker` container instead:

`sudo docker exec MySQL_CONTAINER_NAME /usr/bin/mysqldump --host=192.168.1.1 -u username --password=password db_name > dump.sql`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pipe it to the remote server where you wish to `copy` your data to:

```sql
mysqldump -u your_db_user_name -p --set-gtid-purged=OFF --triggers --routines --events --compress --skip-lock-tables --verbose your_local_sql_db_name | mysql -u your_db_user_name -p -h your_remote_server_ip your_remote_server_db_name
```

You need to have created the db on your remote sql server.

Using the above command, I was able to copy from my local sql server version 8.0.23 to my remote sqlserver running 8.0.25

Answer (score -4):

This is how you would restore a backup after you successfully backup your .sql file

```
mysql -u [username] [databasename]
```

And choose your sql file with this command:

```
source MY-BACKED-UP-DATABASE-FILE.sql
```

Comment: That is how you *restore* a backup, not how you create one.