# Back up selected tables in mysql using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

How can we backup selected tables in mysql server using JAVA

Comment: Java is not an acronym and should not be written in all caps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8444108/977676 :D

Comment: Is it possible to select tables to be backup, when using mysqldump?

Comment: Read the link. And yes it is.