# SQL Import/Export by using MYSQL command line

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database-backups

Currently I am use Wamp server and PHP Platfrom and we want sql dump for my database;
I am used below command for export/dump of MYSQL database.

```
1.mysql> mysqldump database1 > d:/database2.sql;
2.mysql> mysqldumo database1 > d:\database2.sql;
```

Both commands are showing below error on my local system and server.

> **Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysqldump 
>   database1 > d:/database2.sql' at line
>   1**

Any one know, how can we resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` is a program independent of the `mysql` program, you need to run it directly from your shell, not from inside the `mysql` program.

See this answer for more information: [How to use MySQL dump from a remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444108/how-to-use-mysql-dump)

Answer (score 1):

**Command should be run from command prompt/Unix Shell.**

Open Command Prompt
Go to Path where you have installed MySQL in your System/Server.
e.g.

- You have installed **MySQL** at `C:\mysql\` Then
- Go to `cd C:\mysql\bin` Press  for Windows
- Go to `cd /var/lib/mysql/bin` ( May be different Path in Linux
  Machine/Server )

Then Type the Following Command to Run SQL Dump

**For Windows**

```
mysqldump --host=localhost -u root -p database1 > D:/database1.sql
mysqldump --host=localhost -u root -p database2 > D:/database2.sql
```

**For Linux**

```
mysqldump --host=localhost -u root -p database1 > /var/backup/database1.sql
mysqldump --host=localhost -u root -p database2 > /var/backup/database2.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through URL, that will might help you

http://technologiessolution.blogspot.in/2013/09/export-and-import-mysql-database-in.html

This link will show how to Export and Import database with `mysqldump`.