# How to import my hosted mysql database to my local host database?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import my hosted mysql database to my local host database. I have the mysql program working on hosted domain but have unable to transfer to home server pc. Please let me know do I do it. thanks

Comment: [**`mysqldump`**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8444108/2518525)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the MySQL Workbench. Under the **Server** tab there are options for **Data export** and **Data import**. So, first you need to establish a connection with the remote host (at which point click on the Server tab) and export the data. Then make a  connection with your local server and import the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this commands from terminal(Linux)

```
mysqldump -u username -pPassword -hHostName databasename > hostedDump.sql
```

Login to MySql and create the database by this command

```
Create database databaseName;
```

Then just import the dump into your database.

```
mysql -u userName -pPassword -h localhost < hostedDump.sql
```

For more reference visit mysql documentation for [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

Comment: Note: The lack of a space between -p and the mysql password is not a typo. However, if you leave the -p flag present, but the actual password blank then you will be prompted for your password. Sometimes this is recommended to keep passwords out of your bash history.